# Simple and double pointers formulas

Tags: c, pointers, tree, double, binary-tree

I made the delete fct binary tree header, and it worked! but i didn't make any effort, i depended on the debugger.

can you explain how to relate between the simple pointers, double pointers and values?

```
Tree **P2,*P1,P; //(P consider it for explanation only)
P1=&P2;

//what type are these
(*P2)->data;
&(*P2)->data;
P1->data;
*P1->data;
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The above diagram shows the memory representation of a pointer to pointer. The first pointer ptr1(`P2` in your case) stores the address of the second pointer ptr2 and the second pointer ptr2(`P1` in your case) stores the address of the variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _s {
    int data;
} Tree;

int main(int argc, char *args[])
{

    /*
     * Arrow operator example
     * foo->bar is equivalent to (*foo).bar
     * it gets the member called 'bar' from the struct that 'foo' points to.
     */

    Tree **P2,*P1;
    P1 = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    P1->data = 789;
    //P1=&P2;               // It's wrong, Incompatible pointer types Tree* and Tree***
    P2 = &P1;               // It's right, p2 points to address of p1
    printf("%d\n", (*P2)->data);     // same as (**P2).data
    printf("%p\n", (void*)  &(*P2)->data);    // same as &(**P2).data,  (void* casting to print address)
    printf("%d\n", P1->data);        // same as (*P1).data
    //printf("%d",*P1->data);        // same as *(P1->data), it's already dereferenced type, you're trying to dereference again??
    free(P1);


    return 0;
}
```